# Bracket Isn't Closing

Tags: 16.04, kill, adobe-brackets

I've installed `Brackets` (Code Editor by `Adobe`) on My `Ubuntu 16.04` machine using an unofficial PPA from webupd8. Everything was okay but after installing few bracket modules and a fresh reboot, Bracket is opening but isn't closing. Even the editor and opened project isn't coming up.

[image: Bracket Hangs, Not closing]

I've tried several attempts including:

- `sudo kill`
- End process from Ubuntu System Monitor

to closing brackets in my Ubuntu machine but nothing works.

After reboot I can run bracket but still the closing problem exist. How can I solve this without uninstalling Bracket and If there is no other way to solve this, then how can I keep my bracket settings same after a fresh install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed that by deleting `state.json` as suggested [here](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/13196#issuecomment-287863642).

Answer (score 1):

Another way to install Brackets without having to physically install libcrypt11 is to get the latest fixed .deb Brackets files for 64 bit and 32 bit systems [here](https://fourthfruit.github.io/fixes/).

Answer (score 0):

Brackets had some issues on Ubuntu 16.04 which were reported in [GitHub  issues](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/12514)

The suggested fix is as follows:

> To get Brackets 1.7 working on Ubuntu 16.04 I followed the following
>   steps:
>
> - Installed libcrypt11 from [here](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-security/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/8993248)
> - For the 32-bit version of libcrypt11 go [here](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-security/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/8993251)
> - Install brackets from the website, NOT the PPA.
> - Disable the PPA if you have it enabled to prevent automatic upgrades.

Comment: See http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16306/can-someone-elaborate-for-me-the-rule-on-using-the-back-tick-for-emphasis, code formatting isn't for emphasing words in a post. Please refrain from using code spans where they're not needed.